# Pandas Multindex join

Tags: pandas

I have the following DataFrames:

Index is Date and Id

```
               Value
Date       Id
2017-01-01 1     1.4
2017-02-01 1     1.4
2017-03-01 1     1.4
2017-01-01 2     1.4
2017-01-02 2     1.4
2017-01-03 2     1.4
```

and a second DatFrame containing general information for Id (index):

```
   V1 V2
Id
1   x  y
2   y  x
```

and I want to create a DataFrame that looks like (with Index Date and Id):

```
   Date      Id   Value  V1   V2
2017-01-01    1    1.4    x    y
2017-02-01    1    1.4    x    y
2017-03-01    1    1.4    x    y
2017-01-01    2    1.4    y    x
2017-01-02    2    1.4    y    x
2017-01-03    2    1.4    y    x
```

I've tried it with pd.join(df1, df2, on='Id') but get a key error.

Comment: Since `"Id"` does not constitute the column names, you get the `KeyError` when you specify it as the `on` parameter. For the given example, a simple left join would get you the right result - `df1.join(df2)`

Comment: @Roby, the Nickil Maveli's solution works perfectly for the given sample data sets

Comment: @MaxU, yes - I had a failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` parameter in [`DF.join()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method takes *column names (or) a `list` of column names*, but you've supplied the index level name `"Id"` to it. Hence it throws that `KeyError` indicating that it cannot find this string while querying for the column names to be used for the very joining purpose.

Instead, do not specify this as `join` by default infers an alignment over the indices unless specified otherwise using the `on` parameter.

For your case, a simple `join` considering the left `DF's` index would yield the right result:

```
df1.join(df2).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

Another alternative wherein you want to specify a particular level name to be used for joining could be achieved by using the [`DF.reindex()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method as shown:

```
df1.join(df2.reindex(index=df1.index, level='Id')).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for what reason I need reindex ?

Comment: If you explicitly want to perform matching across the `"Id"` level, then the `reindex` solution would make it happen for you. But then, `join` seems to infer the common index levels implicitly, so is a favored syntax according to me. It was included just to provide a different perspective to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if my way here is the recommended one, but I have certainly got this working:

```
df1.reset_index(levels=['Date','Id'])
#This makes your index just columns in the dataframe
df2.reset_index....
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Date','Id'])
```